# Curl -d to Alamofire

Tags: ios, django, swift, curl, alamofire

Following this page (https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html), I was able to setup OAuth for my django project.

The following curl command gives me a token to access resource.

```
curl -X POST 
-d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" 
-u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

However, when I send request using Alamofire, things are a bit strange. This is my code

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
         .authenticate(user: client_ID, password: client_Secret)
```

where parameter is a dictionary

```
[
 "password": <password>, 
 "grant_type": password, 
 "username": <username>
]
```

Using curl command, I can see from Django that request.POST.items() returns the list of parameters. However, using Alamofire, there is nothing. The parameters appeared in request.body instead!

This problem is driving me crazy. Any help will be grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your curl command is posting as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, whereas you are forcing to post as json (`.JSON`). For this reason the request has passed as `application/json` to your django and you are seeing the parameter in body instead of `POST.items()`.

So remove this from your code `encoding: .JSON`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I figured that out last night, and things are going well now!