# io9 - Alamofire token request fails with 401 error depsite curl from debugPrint works

Tags: ios, django, oauth-2.0, alamofire, django-authentication

My question is along the line of a question which has been asked before at [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332221/curl-d-to-alamofire).

I am using Alamofire 3.2.1, XCode 7.3, iOS9.

Here is my code with the intention to obtain a token from OAuth server (localhost) implemented by django oauth toolkit:

```
let params = ["grant_type": "password",
                  "username": "rosa",
                  "password": "rosa1234"]

    let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params).authenticate(user: __clientID, password: __clientSecret)

    debugPrint(request)

    request.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
            debugPrint(response)

            if (error != nil) {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return completionHandler(token: nil, error: error)
            }

            // call the completionHandler function (object) to deal with data further
            return completionHandler(token: json.string, error: nil)
        })
```

The debug print of request gives a working curl command, which works on a command line:

```
curl -i \
-X POST \
-u PrtRUN9ra7LHCYWbiReaAjO9I26lJhLhRSAUJgtr:kTvxqKmClDAL3tbdyZdyBZgsfsfXtagMpZyFjSZwpIknxM43l6ZIvJxJGXu2J2FuHf4JMLfopDoAzkF6vHSRq4GZkbnEZSmmUnMvkhMvSucbhWUdzCpxuj9qtc8beaQ3 \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
-H "User-Agent: IntelliCafe/xsoft.IntelliCafe (1; OS Version 9.3 (Build 13E230))" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
-d "grant_type=password&password=rosa1234&username=rosa" \
"http://localhost:8000/o/token/"
```

But the code does not work in my app. The error is 401:

```
    Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7d183950> { URL: http://localhost:8000/o/token/ } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 11 Apr 2016 20:43:48 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;} }) 
Optional(Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 401" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 401})
```

This problem is driving me crazy. Any help will be grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a django rest view to print out the meta data of the request and found out the clientID and clientSecret are not embedded/processed properly by the django server implementation.

Using the Authorization header as shown in Alamofire documentation works.